# Guidelines to set MetaspaceSize - java 8

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-8, out-of-memory, metaspace

What is the default value of MetaspaceSize for 64-bit servers? I couldn't find it in the official documentation.

I'm observing that in a server JVM process, at times, the GC frequency becomes high and keeps growing. If I restart the service a few times, it returns to stable. I think its due to the JRE upgrade.

JVM Heap max size is set to be 6GB but when this problem occurs, we see only 3GB heap being used. Metaspace grows by very little and is almost always full. I tried increasing the metaspace to 1GB and it improves the throughput.

I think what is happening is Metaspace by default is set to a very low value and thus GC kicks in. High water mark is continuously increased(again by a very low amount) every time a GC occurs.

I want to set the MetaspaceSize (not sure what is the current value).

Oracle docs say there are no guidelines to know what to set MetaspaceSize to. But is there a way to find out what would be the correct value to set it to?

One hint I got from Oracle docs is this:

`If the committed space available for class metadata as a percentage of the total committed space for class metadata is greater than MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio, then the high-water mark will be lowered. If it is less than MinMetaspaceFreeRatio, then the high-water mark will be raised.`

But still not able to figure out how to stabilize the GCs..I have three questions:

1. What is the default MetaspaceSize on 64 bit servers?
2. What are the default ratios: MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio, MinMetaspaceFreeRatio set to? Answer: It shows Min is 40, Max is 70
3. How to go about deciding oon a Metaspacesize value?

Comment: `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version -XX:+UseG1GC | grep Metaspace`

Comment: “*I think what is happening is Metaspace by default is set to a very low value and thus GC kicks in*”—Why do you think that? Your explanation contains no hint about why the first thing to blame should be the Metaspace and not just the heap (or available RAM) in general.

Comment: @Holger I've updated the description with details on why I think metaspace is the issue. Metaspace was not the first one to blame.

Comment: Good question. We are interested in the answer too. We recently developed a new webapp in java 8 and after deploying to server realized that it is using over 2.5 GB of Headspace and 90 GB of meatspace and loading over 17 K classes. So we are also interested in understanding how to tune the VM for Java 8 webapps

Comment: @Savior you would not need `UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` to find out those _default_ values for `Metaspace`, though.

Answer (score 18):

`MetaspaceSize` is the value when a `Full GC` will be triggered, its *not* initial space nor maximum space.

The default value for it is `20MB` (at least on `jdk-8` to `jdk-13`):

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MetaspaceSize
```

will produce:

```
size_t MetaspaceSize = 21807104 // 20MB
```

This means that when `Metaspace` reaches `20MB` a `Full GC` will be triggered and if you can avoid it, that would be good.

Considering how much data metaspace can potentially hold (methods, annotations, etc), it seems to me that `20MB` is a very small value to start with. Unfortunately, choosing a correct value is not easy.

You have two options, enable gc logging `-Xlog:gc` and let the app run for some time and then find instances like:

```
[Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) ...]
```

And understand from these what you need to set and how.

*Or* start the process with:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
```

connect to the `PID` via :

```
jcmd <YourJVMPID> VM.metaspace
```

And find lines like these:

```
 Virtual space:
    Non-class space:        8.00 MB reserved,       4.25 MB ( 53%) committed
    Class space:            1.00 GB reserved,     512.00 KB ( <1%) committed
    Both:                   1.01 GB reserved,       4.75 MB ( <1%) committed
```

And get the value from `Non-class space` after the app has been running for at least a day IMHO.

There are various other settings on how to control `Metaspace`, which you can find out like this:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep Metaspace
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the most interesting question is #3 so I'll answer that one first. The way I approached it was to run my application for 24 hours with gc logging turned on using these settings:

```
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCCause
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-Xloggc:gc.log
```

Then I did this:

```
grep Metaspace gc.log
```

and saw that the "used" value quickly grew to 80M ... so I set MetaspaceSize to 100M

```
-XX:MetaspaceSize=100M
```

and voila - no more gcs due to metaspace.

It looks like @Pillar's comment pretty much answered your first 2 questions on how to determine the default Metaspace settings for your implementation ... I'll include it here for completeness:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version -XX:+UseG1GC | grep Metaspace
```

Technically, @Pillar's comment doesn't tell you the default Metaspace size for any 64 bit server, but but that's because your first question is a bit misleading, since according to the documentation these defaults vary per implementation.

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html

Specifically, the part at the bottom where it says, "The default size of MetaspaceSize is platform-dependent and ranges from 12 MB to about 20 MB"

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 8, the two most important metaspace settings can be controlled with the following command-line options:

- `-XX:MetaspaceSize=N` - when the space initially committed for class metadata reaches this level, a garbage collection is induced; the level may be subsequently raised or lowered depending on collection results,
- `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=N` - sets the maximum size of the metaspace.

Quoting [*Oracle HotSpot VM Garbage Collection Tuning Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/other-considerations.htm#JSGCT-GUID-B29C9153-3530-4C15-9154-E74F44E3DAD9),

- *"Class metadata is deallocated when the corresponding Java class is unloaded. Java classes are unloaded as a result of garbage collection, and garbage collections may be induced to unload classes and deallocate class metadata. When the space committed for class metadata reaches a certain level (a high-water mark), a garbage collection is induced. After the garbage collection, the high-water mark may be raised or lowered depending on the amount of space freed from class metadata. The high-water mark would be raised so as not to induce another garbage collection too soon. The high-water mark is initially set to the value of the command-line option `-XX:MetaspaceSize`. [...] The default size of `-XX:MetaspaceSize` is platform-dependent and ranges from 12 MB to about 20 MB."*
- *"The amount of native memory that can be used for class metadata is by default unlimited. Use the option `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` to put an upper limit on the amount of native memory used for class metadata."*

The WildFly application server sets the metaspace options in [`standalone.conf`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/70708471927c127f77bb2f501a7a0bb8307861ac/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/bin/standalone.conf#L53) to 96 MB / 256 MB respectively as follows:

```
... -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m ...
```

However, `MaxMetaspaceSize` might need to be much larger in large production applications as it needs to contain metadata for all loaded classes in your application and you might want to specify a higher value for `MetaspaceSize` to avoid early garbage collections.

See also @Eugene's answer for instructions how to empirically determine metaspace settings.

Comment: this is wrong, `Metaspace` does not set the initial _nor_ minimum space.

Comment: @Eugene, can you clarify a bit more? I don't mention `Metaspace`, only  `MetaspaceSize` and `MaxMetaspaceSize`. Do you mean that the `XX:MetaspaceSize` has no effect even though [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/other-considerations.htm#JSGCT-GUID-28448147-EC4C-4C94-9A54-54152AD21CB8) document it? If yes, can you explain why you think so or refer to empirical tests?

Comment: my bad, I meant to say `MetaspaceSize`, even the article you mentioned says "high water-mark", _not_ initial or minimum size, as such one of your statements is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Note that "sets the initial size of the metaspace" is a verbatim copy from the _Java Performance: The Definitive Guide_ book, page 398. If it is wrong, can you suggest the right description of what `MetaspaceSize` does?

Comment: @Eugene, now I see your answer below, I didn't notice it before. Well written answer, gave my +1! I'll update my answer and refer to your answer.

Comment: this is wrong, metaspace is not a initial value. The initial value of metaspace is 0, there is not initial metaspace. See answer above. Edit or delete your answer to avoid misinformation.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior, I changed the answer to quote Oracle docs verbatim, please check the amended `MetaspaceSize` definition. Does this look good to you?

Comment: It does, thanks, in widlfy/eap we sometimes suggest to change this property on the xml (standalone/domain.xml) instead of  `.conf` file, but your answer is acceptable. Hago.